# Counting between date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have lots of employee holiday records which show the holiday start and end days.  I need to work out how many holidays each employee has taken between 2 dates, i.e. `2015-01-01 00:00:00` to `2015-02-01 00:00:00`.

How do I deal with holidays where the holiday starts before that range or ends after that range?

- For example, if `employee 1` took off `2015-01-10` to `2015-01-15`, that's fine as 5 days holiday
- But if `employee 2` took off `2015-12-25` to `2015-01-05`, that should only count as 5 days holiday
- The same for the other side, i.e. if `employee 3` took off `2015-01-25` to `2015-02-05`, that should only count as 5 days holiday

Comment: Your question would be clearer with sample output and desired results.

Comment: You need a calendar with all dates, telling if it's working day or not.

Answer (score 1):

Say your employee holiday table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeHoliday (
    EmployeeId INT,
    HolidayStart DATETIME,
    HolidayEnd DATETIME
)
```

The following query returns the number of days per employee, between the two specified dates (variables):

```
DECLARE @CountFromDate AS DATETIME = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @CountToDate AS DATETIME = '2015-02-01'

SELECT EmployeeId,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,
        CASE WHEN @CountFromDate < HolidayStart THEN HolidayStart ELSE @CountFromDate END,
        CASE WHEN @CountToDate > HolidayEnd THEN HolidayEnd ELSE @CountToDate END
        )
    ) AS HolidaysHeld
FROM EmployeeHoliday
GROUP BY EmployeeId
```

If you don't want this query to output employees that only had holidays outside the specified interval of time, include the following `WHERE`-clause just before the `GROUP BY` part of the query:

```
WHERE HolidayStart <= @CountToDate AND HolidayEnd >= @CountFromDate
```

Comment: I hesitated to give +1 as this doesn't have a `WHERE` clause *(returning 0 days for potentially the vast majority of the table; for holidays that don't overlap the specified range)*, but does explicitly state the assumed schema.

Comment: This was intentional, as some use cases includes knowing which employees did not have any holidays in the chosen period...

Comment: Then I'd suggest joining on an employee table; as present it gives 0's only for employees that had holidays and where none of them were in that date range, but misses out new starters who have not yet had or booked any holidays.

Comment: You're right. Adding a comment to the question to address this point.

Answer (score 1):

You use date logic.  Other databases have `least()` and `greatest()` functions to help with this.  In SQL Server, you can use somewhat more complicated `case` statements.  The result is something like this:

```
select h.employee_id,
       sum(datediff(day, 
                    (case when h.start < @StartDate then @StartDate else h.start end),
                    (case when h.end > @EndDate then @EndDate else h.end end)
                   )
          ) as DaysOnHoliday
from holidays h
where h.start <= @EndDate and h.end >= @StartDate
group by h.employee_id
```

Comment: Although `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` are lovely, they can really bite with NULLABLE data.  `MIN({NULL, 0}) => 0` vs `LEAST(NULL, 0) => NULL`.  `CASE` statements are longer but give much more explicit control :)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @datebeg datetime = '20150101', @dateend datetime = '20150201'

select e.employeeid, sum(datediff(day, case when @datebeg < h.datebeg then h.datebeg else @datebeg end,
                                       case when @dateend > h.dateend then h.dateend else @dateend end))
from holiday h 
where @datebeg <= h.dateend and @dateend >= h.datebeg
group by h.employeeid
```

Answer (score 0):

you try SELECT date1-date2 from tablename;